# Is it possible to increase processor speed via windows?

Tags: windows, cpu

**EDITED:** On windows 10 with 2.5 GHZ max while running an app, I locked my system and closed the lid right after, noticed the percentage of the CPU usage increased for the task and then goes back to normal(a few minutes after I have signed back in) in Task manager. Is there a way to have the CPU be at 100% or 90% usage in Taskmanager by increasing its clock speed so the app can as well run faster?

Comment: kindly downvote to prove you have 12 heads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's likely happening is the result of a feature called [SpeedStep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep). There should be an option in the BIOS to enable/disable it (it may be listed under EIST).

If you're simply disabling it so that your app runs faster, you're probably going to be wasting CPU cycles and power. The CPU is smart enough to know when the app needs more resources and will increase it's frequency up to the advertised spec until it's no longer needed - then step back down to a lower idle frequency to minimise power draw and heat generation.

Comment: so from the bios I can influence the clock speed... thanks

Comment: If your BIOS supports it, yes. That's where all your overclocking (or underclocking) would happen. Take care not to make any changes without researching first. You can very easily damage your CPU by pushing it too far/feeding it too much voltage. High recommend only changing the EIST/SpeedStep setting.

Answer (score 3):

Task Manager shows high CPU for a few seconds upon starting and then reflects normal CPU.  That is entirely normal. Keeping your CPU at 100% will just lead to higher temperatures.  Just allow the CPU to manage its own rate. It will increase when needed

Comment: I am not bothered about the temperature, I only ask to know if its possible

Comment: I don't think you can set the CPU to always run at 100%. In most cases, workstation / laptop CPUs are not designed to run full throttle all the time. So the CPU itself contains control design and I have not seen settings in BIOS that will override that.